# Editable content area for user with restricted access

Tags: wordpress, widget, panel

I'm building a blog for a client and they need to be able to edit a paragraph of text in the sidebar. I currently have it setup as a 'Better Text' widget which I can quickly edit for them.

I don't want to give them access to the widgets, etc but they want to be able to edit it themselves. Is there an easy way to add a custom write panel kind-of-thing that's independent of the post & page structure?

I know I could create a separate post category and pull the particular post into the template but i'm looking for something different.

Anyone got any ideas? thanks in advance,
Greg.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add a a custom field for that specific page, and let them have a login which allows them to edit that content?

The point of using a CMS, is to allow the customer to edit the content themselves.

Comment: The site is only made up of 'posts' and therefore there aren't any 'pages' to add a custom field to.

Comment: Last I checked, Posts have Custom fields as well.

Comment: Was looking more for help than sarcastic comments, but thanks.

Comment: Download the latest version of WP and you will see that you can add custom fields to a Post. So I don't see any sarcasm in that.